# Only one $(m+1)$-plane containing $m$-plane and a given point

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

> In the Affine space $A$, given $m-$plane $\alpha$ and a point $P\notin\alpha$. Prove that there is only one $(m+1)-$plane containing $\alpha$ and $P$.

I can prove through $m+1$ independent points, there exists only one $m-$plane ($m\geq 0$), but I don't know how it can help prove this problem. Can anyone have any hints for me? Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a homework problem for a linear algebra class, so I won't give a solution. But, I am willing to help. First, what are the definitions of _affine space_ and _$m$-plane_ that you are using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: here is the definitions of affine space in page 2: http://dma.aq.upm.es/profesor/rueda_s/srueda_archivos/Geometry2011/Apuntes/week5_rev2.pdf

Comment: @NaturalLogZ Let $A$ be the affine space and $\overrightarrow{A}$ be its associated vector space. Assume $I\in A$ and $\vec{\alpha}$ is a subspace of $\vec{A}$. We call the set $$\alpha=\{M\in\alpha | \overrightarrow{IM}\in \vec{\alpha}\}$$ is a plane and define dim$\alpha$=dim$\vec{\alpha}$. If dim$\vec{\alpha}=m$, then we call it $m-$plane.

Comment: Okay, so now you can use that definition to describe the $m$-plane $\alpha$, and in particular, you know there exists an $m$-dimensional subspace $\vec{\alpha}$ of $\vec{A}$ associated with $\alpha$. From there, can you construct an $m+1$-dimensional subspace $\vec{\beta}$ of $\vec{A}$ that contains $\vec{\alpha}$? What would it take for the $(m+1)$-plane associated with $\vec{\beta}$, lets call it $\beta$ to be a solution to the problem?

Comment: Alternatively, you could go the route of using the statement you said you know how to prove. The point $P$ is going to be one of your points, and an $m$-plane needs to have $m+1$ independent points. You would just need to show that $P$ is independent of those points, and that the $(m+2)$-plane you get from your lemma contains all of $A$.

Comment: I understood your second approach. But it should be $(m+1)-$plane, not $(m+2)-$plane.  Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @Bob you should generally edit your question to include relevant definitions, etc. not dump them in a conversation in the comments. Please read the help and meta pages for this site about writing good questions.